# how do I turn on multi factor authentication for a user?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I know I can go into the user pools console and turn on mfa, but if I want the user to be able to toggle mfa on and off how do I do that?  I'm using objective c.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, wasn't paying attention.  It's the code at the bottom:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html